# Draw magnetic field lines or vector field of a magnetic dipole - Python/Matplotlib

Tags: computational-physics, software

In the Wikipedia [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_moment#Effects_of_an_external_magnetic_field) on magnetic moments, subsection "Effects on environment" defines the magnetic field **H** of a magnetic dipole moment. Additionally the magnetic field lines of this field are drawn:

[image]

I want to reproduce this picture using Python - Matplotlib. I believe that my result is correct but it is visually poorly represented.

[image]

Here is the Python Code that generated the picture above. Does someone know how fix this, so that I get a similar picture as in the wiki article.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

x,y = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(-5,5,10),np.linspace(-5,5,10)) # coordinates for the position vector r
m = [0, 1]  # magnetic moment of the magnetic dipole moment

mr = m[0] * x + m[1] * y # dot product m * r

r_squared = x**2 + y**2
factor = 1 / ( np.sqrt(r_squared)**5 * 4 * np.pi) # pre factor, that is  multiplied with the vector 

u = factor * (3 * x * mr - m[0] * r_squared)
v = factor * (3 * y * mr - m[1] * r_squared)



plt.quiver(x,y,u,v)
plt.show()
```

To do this, on need to define **m** = (m_x, m_y) = (0, m_y) (as described in the fig description) and compute the dot product **r*m** = (r_x * m_x + r_y * m_y). Insert this into the formula for **H** and split the equations into its x and y part (cartesian coordinates).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about using Matlab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try using the scale parameter of quiver and play around with that to decrease the arrow length. If you want a picture that resembles the image you linked you could also look into using [plt.streamplot()](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.streamplot.html) to avoid the clutter that plotting all the vectors individually brings with it.

Answer (score 1):

When I had to write such code to draw magnetic field lines, I found it easier to select a set of starting points and integrate outward, following the direction of the field and placing points. Then you can place the arrows where you feel like, perhaps at a regular spacing along the lines.

I would recommend adapting code from [this Python Matplotlib Tips blog](https://pythonmatplotlibtips.blogspot.com/2017/12/plot-continuous-magnetic-field-lines.html).

Note that without modifications, `pyplot.quiver` **will not space field lines properly** to represent magnet field line density and will not connect the lines. Below is an example plot (from the docs) of "bare" `pyplot.quiver`. (If you want connected lines, you can use `pyplot.streamplot`, but when testing I found this still does not space the lines properly.)

[image: Quiver example plot]

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this using matplotlib, but there is a nice python library for the purpose:

https://github.com/CD3/VectorFieldPlot

Documentation: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/User:Geek3/VectorFieldPlot

Examples: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Valid_SVG_created_with_VectorFieldPlot_code

Comment: You can do this using Matplotlib, see @Wihtedeka answer.